# optimization of coefficients with constant sum of inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Does anybody knows if there is an easy solution to the following problem:

Given $A = [a_1, a_2, ... a_n]$ and K, find B = $[b_1, b_2,...b_n]$ that minimizes $AB^T$ such that $\sum_{i}^{n}\frac{1}{b_i} = K$?

Comment: Yes, Lagrange multipliers...

Comment: I need a life...

Comment: @copper.hat amen

Comment: thanks! would you add a pointer or a some more insights? i'm not familiar with linear algebra and have to code this for an application.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Looks like I spoke too soon. Let me see if I can write up something.

Comment: In retrospect this is fairly clear if we look at the surface ${1 \over x} + {1 \over y} = K$, and consider the intersection with any family of parallel lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As copper.hat suggests: Lagrange multipliers!

We want to minimize $f(B) = AB^T$ subject to the constraint $g(B) = \sum_{i}^{n}\frac{1}{b_i} = K$.  We can find all critical points by solving the system
$$
\nabla f = -\lambda \nabla g\\
g(B) = K
$$
Where
$$
\nabla f = A = [a_1,\dots,a_n]\\
\nabla g = -\left[\frac{1}{b_1^2}, \dots, \frac{1}{b_n^2}\right]
$$
So, we have the system of equations
$$
a_1 = \frac{\lambda}{b_1^2}\\
\vdots\\
a_n = \frac{\lambda}{b_n^2}\\
\frac{1}{b_1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{b_n} = K
$$
Solving the first $n$ lines for $\lambda$ yields
$$
\lambda = a_1 b_1^2 = \cdots = a_n b_n^2
$$
So that the sign of $\lambda$ must match the sign of $a_i$ for each $i$.  Assume, without loss of generality then, that all $a_i > 0$ (if any $a_i$ have signs that don't match, then there can be no critical points).
$$
b_i = 
\pm\sqrt{\lambda/a_i}
$$
So, plugging into $g(B) = K$, we have
$$
\frac{\pm\sqrt{a_1} \pm \cdots \pm \sqrt{a_n}}{\sqrt{\lambda}} = K \implies\\
\lambda = \frac{(\pm\sqrt{a_1} \pm \cdots \pm \sqrt{a_n})^2}{K^2}
$$
That is, we have $2^n$ possibilities to check for $\lambda$.  It suffices to take each of these $\lambda$, compute $b_i = \pm\sqrt{\lambda/a_i}$, compute $AB^T$ for each such choice, and select the vector $B$ that produced the minimal $AB^T$.

This process could probably be shortened with a second derivative test.  I'll think about that...

Answer (score 1):

When $A\ne0$ and $n\ge2$, no minimum exists, because $AB^T$ is unbounded below. More specifically, suppose $a_1\ne0$. Let $b_1=-ca_1$ and $b_2=b_3=\ldots=b_n=(n-1)/(K+\frac1{ca_1})$ for some nonnegative $c$ that is greater than some large positive number (so that $K+\frac1{ca_1}\ne0$). Then $\sum_i\frac1b_i=K$ and $b_2,\ldots,b_n$ are bounded. Hence $AB^T$ is equal to $-c|a_1|^2$ plus a bounded quantity, and it approaches $-\infty$ when $c\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if $a\neq 0$ and $n>1$, there is no solution to the problem in that it can have arbitrarily small values.

If $n=1$ the answer is given by the constraint so there is nothing to be done, so suppose $n>1$.

If $a=0$, any $b$ will do, so suppose $a \neq 0$.

So, suppose $a_1 \neq 0$. Then choose $x_2=\cdots = x_{n-1} = \beta$ such that
$K'=K-(n-1)\beta \neq 0$. Then an upper bound for the problem is
$\inf_{{1 \over x_1} + {1 \over x_n} = K'} (a_1 x_1+a_n x_n  )$.

Now choose $x_n = {1 \over K' - {1 \over x_1}} $ to get the upper bound
$\inf_{x \neq {1 \over K'} } (a_1 x + a_n {1 \over K' - {1 \over x}} )$. Now let $x \to (-\operatorname{sgn} a_1) \infty$, and notice that the problem is unbounded below.

Comment: Not quick enough, it seems...

Comment: You are quick enough. Just not short enough. ;D

Answer (score 0):

If we assume all $a_i>0$ and all $b_i>0$, then there is the following nice application of the AM/HM inequality:
\begin{align*}
\sum_i a_i b_i
&= \Bigg(\sum_j \sqrt{a_j}\Bigg) \left(\sum_i \frac{\sqrt{a_i}}{\sum_j \sqrt{a_j}} \cdot \sqrt{a_i} b_i \right) \\
&\ge \Bigg(\sum_j \sqrt{a_j}\Bigg) \left/ \left(\sum_i \frac{\sqrt{a_i}}{\sum_j \sqrt{a_j}} \cdot \frac1{\sqrt{a_i} b_i} \right) \right. \\
&= \frac1K \Bigg(\sum_j \sqrt{a_j}\Bigg)^2
\end{align*}
with equality when all $\sqrt{a_i} b_i$ are equal, that is, when
$$ \frac1{b_i} = \frac{K\sqrt{a_i}}{\sum_j \sqrt{a_j}} $$
for each $i$.

Comment: Wait, i see the result is the same than applying Lagrange multipliers with positive values, but i can't understand a step. AM/HM says that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i{x_i} \ge \frac{n}{\sum_i{1/x_i}}$

So this applied to the second line should be:

\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_i \frac{\sqrt{a_i}}{\sum_j \sqrt{a_j}} \cdot \sqrt{a_i} b_i \right)
&\ge 1 \left/ \left(\sum_i \frac{1}{\sum_j \sqrt{a_j}} \cdot \frac1{\sqrt{a_i}\sqrt{a_i} b_i} \right) \right.
\end{align*}

which doesn't help me get rid of $\sqrt{a_i}$?

Comment: Weighted AM/HM: $\sum \lambda_i x_i \ge 1\left/\left(\sum \lambda_i/x_i\right)\right.$ if $\sum\lambda_i=1$ and everything positive.  Take $\lambda_i = \sqrt{a_i}\left/\sum_j \sqrt{a_j}\right.$ and $x_i = \sqrt{a_i}b_i$.